# ¿Saben porque tengo este error 500 internal server error en blazor?

Tags: .net-6.0

```
Este es el codigo de mi Api estoy recuperando la informacion de las tablas Factura y Detalle Factura:
    [HttpGet]
   public async Task <ActionResult<List<Factura>>> Get()
   {

       try
       {
           var _context = new ApplicationDbContext();

           var resultado = await _context.Facturas.Join(_context.DetalleFacturas, f => f.Id_Factura,
               d => d.Id_Factura, (f, d) => new
               {


                   Factura = f,
                   DetalleFacturas = d
               }
               ).ToListAsync();

           return Ok(resultado);
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {

           return BadRequest(ex);
       }

      
   }
```

Este es el Codigo en el componente blazor que estoy intentando recuperar los datos
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{

```
         try
         {
              facturas = await http.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Factura>>("https://localhost:7185/Reportes");
    
    
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             message = ex.Message;
         }
    
    
     }
```

La parte de el Api funciona bien ya que recoge los datos de las base de datos el error radica en el codigo blazor, hasta ahora no habia tenido ningun error.